# How can I find this power series expansion?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am doing a question that is slowly leading me up to finding specific series by having me show general results along the way.

The first is that if $\phi : C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous where $C$ is the unit circle, then:

$$ g_{\phi}(w) = \int_C \frac{\phi(z)}{z-w} \; dz$$ is holomorphic $\forall w \in D = \{z \in \mathbb C \; | \; |z| < 1\} $

The second is that if $\phi = F|_C$ for some holomorphic $F: \{z \in \mathbb C \; | \; 1-\epsilon < |z| < 1+\epsilon \} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ then $g_{\phi}(w)$ is the restriction of some function holomorphic on $D(0,1+\epsilon)$

Finally, I need to find the series expansion of $g_{\phi}(w) $ about $0$ in terms of $f_{\phi}(\theta) $ where $f_{\phi}(\theta) = \phi(e^{i\theta})$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

I have done the first two things, and have gotten as far as the conclusion that if:

$$  g_{\phi}(w) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} c_nw^n, \;\; \forall w \in D(0, 1+\epsilon),  $$

then:

$$ c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{g_{\phi}(w)}{w^n}\; dw    $$

$$ \Rightarrow c_n = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2i} \int_C \frac{1}{w^n}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{i\theta}f_{\phi}(\theta)}{e^{i\theta} - w} \;dz\;dw$$

Past this, I really don't know how to proceed. How can I simplify this further and get an expression in terms of $f_{\phi}(\theta)$ for $c_n$? Is there some simple theorem that I'm forgetting that might make this simpler and help me realise what I need to do? Have I made a mistake at any point?

In my proof for the first result I showed that $g_{\phi}'(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-w)^2} \; dz$ and I don't know if maybe that will come in handy for this part?

Any hints and help you may be able to offer would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: look at page 9 of [this document](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/notes_2014-15/04_cauchy.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie So, if I'm understanding this correctly, $c_n = \frac{g_{\phi}^{(n)}(0)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{\phi(z)}{z^{n+1}} \; dz = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{f_{\phi}(\theta)}{e^{in\theta}} \; d\theta$ but I am unsure with how to proceed now. Is this as simplified as I can get or is there some way I can evaluate this?

Comment: You understand that $c_n= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f_{\phi}(\theta)e^{-in\theta} \; d\theta$ is nothing else than a (complex in general) Fourier coefficient, thus "ready to be computed".